# Use two way data binding in kotlin data class

Tags: android, android-databinding

How can we use  two way data binding in Kotlin data class? I have search it but unable to find the way of using two day data binding with Kotlin data class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? Data binding is an XML feature. Regardless a data class is no different to a normal class in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
data class User(
    private val _id: Long,
    private var _name: String,
) : BaseObservable() {

    val id: Long
        get() = _id

    var name: String
        @Bindable get() = _name
        set(value) {
            _name = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
        }

    @Bindable
    var age: Int = false
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.age)
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

rather then databinding in kotlin you have to use viewBinding because its easy to use more
and its official supported in android

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: View binding and data binding are completely different so I'm not sure they can be compared. Regardless, have you got a source saying data binding isn't officially supported?

Comment: but google support first viewBinding rather then data binding now you can go with viewbinding ...please consider my review i am not telling you to go with wrong direction

Comment: But even if this was true, view binding isn't the same? You can't achieve anything data binding related with view binding. If you're going to make big claims like this, a source or reason is needed.

Comment: go with offical doc and see - http://prntscr.com/1134ren after if your daoud is clear then voteup bro

Comment: Yes exactly, so *if you don't need the features of data binding* then don't use it because of the reasons you've linked. However view binding doesn't have the features that data binding does, as the screenshot mentions in the bottom half.